# Randomly rotating camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am making a game to where the camera will randomly tilt upside down and fix itself in random intervals and I would like to do this for aslong as the game goes. I have tried testing out this code, but it seems there must be a better way of doing it. Any recommendations on how to improve this code or a totally different optimized solution.

```
public Camera cam;
    float time = 0;
    private float cumulativeRotation = 0f;
    private int rotationSpeed = 1;

    public static int test = 0;

    private int minNumber;
    private int minNumber2;
    private int maxNumber;
    private void Start() {
        minNumber = Random.Range(5, 15);
        minNumber2 = Random.Range(16, 25);
        maxNumber = Random.Range(26, 40); 
    }
    int count = 0;
    void Update() {
        
        time += Time.deltaTime;

        float rotationThisFrame = Mathf.Min(180f - cumulativeRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        
        if (time >= minNumber && time <= minNumber2 && test == 0) {
            cam.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 180.0f * Time.deltaTime);
            cumulativeRotation += rotationThisFrame;
            if (cumulativeRotation >= 1f) {
                // We are done rotating. Stop rotating on further frames.
                cam.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, 180.0f * Time.deltaTime);
                test = 1;
                // Reset cumulativeRotation tracker for next time.
                cumulativeRotation = 0f;

                minNumber = minNumber + minNumber2;
                Debug.Log("MIN NUMBER: " + minNumber);
                minNumber2 = minNumber2 + minNumber2;
                Debug.Log("MIN NUMBER2 : " + minNumber2);

            }
            
        }
        
        if(time >= minNumber2  && time <= maxNumber && test == 1) {
            cam.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 180.0f * Time.deltaTime);
            cumulativeRotation += rotationThisFrame;
            if (cumulativeRotation >= 1f) {
                // We are done rotating. Stop rotating on further frames.
                cam.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, 180.0f * Time.deltaTime);
                test = 0;
                // Reset cumulativeRotation tracker for next time.
                cumulativeRotation = 0f;
                maxNumber = maxNumber + maxNumber;
                Debug.Log("MaxNumber: " + maxNumber);
            }

        }
    
 
       
    }
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? what needs to be better?

Comment: It is okay on the first rotation (upside down), but it seems to never rotate back (right-side up). It never seems to do more than 1 rotation